# SQLAlchemy/Elixir property to access row from seperate table without using multiple select queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We have a Person model

```
from project.model import User

class Person(Entity, PersonHook):
    ...
    @property
    def user_name(self):
        u = User.get(self.user_id)
        return u.user_name if u else ""
```

When we are doing a big query for Person and accessing Person.user_name it will create a select statement for every single Person from the User table.

Is it possible to load the two objects Person and User at the same time?

Our project is using the old and outdated Elixir declarative layer for SQLAlchemy.

In the DB they have a relationship of User.user_id and Person.person_id I have tried several forms of sqlalchemys relationship
`user = relationship('User', primaryjoin='foreign(Person.user_id) == User.user_id')`
`user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user_id], primaryjoin = 'User.user_id == Person.user_id')`
But all I get is `<RelationshipProperty at 0x7f8fdd5ee5a0; no key>`

Comment: I don't know about Elixir, but modern SQLAlchemy ORM has different load strategies for relationships, e.g. joined load, subquery load, etc. which would automatically prefetch related objects for you.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of tags before tagging. [tag:elixir] has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: You are correct @mudasobwa .  

I was a bit tired and should have explained what I have have tried so far.
In the DB they have a relationship of User.user_id and Person.person_id

I have tried several forms of sqlalchemys relationship
`user = relationship('User', primaryjoin='foreign(Person.user_id) == User.user_id')`

`user = relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user_id],
                      primaryjoin = 'User.user_id == Person.user_id')`

But all I get is <RelationshipProperty at 0x7f8fdd5ee5a0; no key>